# Ошибка при подключении библиотеки thread

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Нашёл [книгу](http://www.manning.com/williams/) по параллелизму на С++ и решил опробовать первый же листинг:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread> 
void hello() 
{
   std::cout<<"Hello Concurrent World\n";
}
int main()
{
   std::thread t(hello); 
   t.join(); 
}
```

Ну и тут же возникла проблема, компилятор (VS2010) не может открыть заголовочный файл thread. Кто может подсказать, как исправить этот недочёт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал пока пользоваться [boost.thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/thread.html), пока новый стандарт не устоялся.
Кстати, создатель библиотеки boost.thread и есть автор приведенной [книги](http://www.manning.com/williams/), так что все примеры оттуда должны работать.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что это новый стандарт C++11. Visual Studio его не полностью поддерживает, там этого файла нет. Попробуй на GCC, там C++11 поддерживается намного лучше, чем в VS. Сюда приделать этот файл не получится. Либо попробуй другие способы для создания многопоточных приложений, их много.

Comment: ну да, книжка издана в 2008 году, а стандарт опубликовали в прошлом месяце. @myasnik90 почитайте книжку, там наверняка должно быть описан набор иструментариев, на котором все примеры должны работать

Answer (score 1):

Студия пока не поддерживает полностью эту часть стандарта C++11. Основано это все на платной, к сожалению, библиотеке [just::thread](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/). Этот пример соберется gcc версии 4.5 и выше.

P.S. Попробуй [boost](http://www.boost.org/) и другие библиотеки.

Comment: У меня нечто подобное собиралось в Linux с помощью gcc 4.4

Comment: У gcc 4.4. есть частичная поддержка :) вполне может собраться.

Comment: gcc4.4 поддерживал частично С++х0, а это все туда уже входило.

Comment: gcc 4.7 все еще частично поддерживает с++11. А в 4.4 лямбд не было :( и треды там тоже очень частично были.

Comment: Я тоже листал эту книгу, и пробовал какой-то такой простейший пример, все работало )))

Comment: Собрал только что этот пример на Debian Squeeze с GCC 4.4.5-8. Все собралось, но при запуске "Segmentation fault" :(

Comment: Я компилил так:

g++ test.cpp -o a -std=c++0x -pthread

Для @AlexWindHope: на мое счастье, я могу писать даже для работы на чем захочу)))

Comment: @mikillskegg - это потому-что вы программируете под линуксом ^.^

Comment: @mikillskegg Спасибо, заработало. Забыл -pthread :)